# Tomcat 6, Primefaces, JSF

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces

A very strange issue happening.
I have developed an application under JSF and Primefaces on tomcat 6 on my local computer. Everything works perfect. 
But when I deploy the application on remote tomcat 6 (Under enterprise RedHat Linux), the primefaces stops working. The funniest part:
the response takes a lot of time, and it returns the generated html (so it seems like it calls the lifecycle). But no components are rendered (there is plain lot of html intermixed with javascript functions) - p:tabView and other components` contents are rendered as simple lines of text.
But as for the Javascript, it states - ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined.
Catalina log file states nothing.

I have no idea what it can be. Is there any idea?

Comment: Did u place primefaces jar in the lib foldrr and jsf jar/s too ?

Comment: As Daniel points out, looks like you don't have the JSF/PrimeFaces libraries in WEB-INF/lib of your web project. Did you make this project using NetBeans, by the way?

Comment: I added the primefaces jar to the WEB-INF/lib. And 1 theme jar. And javax.faces.jar. 3 jars in total. I develop it in eclipse.

Comment: Are you testing it in Eclipse's embedded server runtime? If yes, I suggest you exporting the war, running your tomcat instance using console and deploy it. Look if it's working. If no problem deploy it to remote.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check what dependencies your project has in eclipse build path. Verify all of them are available in your remote server . All the dependencies in build path should be copied to the lib folder in war file you are generating(unless they are runtime like tomcat,jdk etc).

2) Verify your web.xml and faces-config.xml is same in your eclipse and war deployed in remote.

If it doesn't work then you can compare the temp folder in your eclipse to the war you are deploying contains everything that is in local.

You can find your local war by searching for your project file in eclipse under your workspace

Answer (score 0):

The problem was security for Tomcat. It did not allow any redirections so the js-files were listed in the links but nothing was fetched. Problem was solved by reinstalling tomcat.